# Start a game from within an action listener

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, actionlistener

I have a Blackjack game that I've made in Java and I want to signal the start of the game by clicking a button. All my action listeners work just fine and all that, but the problem lies in that I can't figure out how to start the game without it running completely within the actionPerformed method. Obviously, a function continuously running within the actionPerformed method will effectively disable the rest of my GUI. Here's a code snippet....

```
go.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
                 // START GAME SOMEHOW but must run outside of action listener
        }
    });
```

Comment: What does the game do when started? It shouldn't have a loop. All the user actions should be events.

Comment: I think a good solution may be to not start the whole game, but rather just deal the cards out and return. However, I would like to know how to start a program from within an action listener. I would imagine it's possible, but I'm new with Java and really these whole computin' machines altogether. Any tips would be much appreciated!!! :)

Comment: Thanks for your replay, JB. Originally I had it initialize a new game, which runs the entire thing within its constructor, so the actionPerformed method simply had the line: "game g = new game()"

However, now that you mention that it should be an event only I'm that much more sure I was doing it the wrong way. haha

Answer (score 7):

> *Obviously, a function continuously running within the actionPerformed method will effectively disable the rest of my GUI.*

This is a valid observation and shows that you have understand the fundamental rule when working with Swing.

Your game is most likely event driven (correct me if I'm wrong) so the action performed by the button should just set the program in a new state, waiting for further events. This is nothing that should be time consuming, and is typically done directly by the EDT.

Of course, if you want to do a fancy start-new-game animation, that needs to be performed in a separate thread, in which case you simply start the animation thread (I would recommend using a SwingWorker though) from within the actionPerformed method, and then return.

In code, I imagine it would look something like this:

```
go.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        // Remove the menu components
        someJPanel.removeAll();

        // Show the game table
        someJPanel.add(new GamePanel());

        someJPanel.revalidate();
        someJPanel.repaint();

        // done. Wait for further user actions.
    }
});
```

Comment: I think this sounds absolutely like what I should be doing. I'm going to implement this and see where it takes me. I'm surprised I got so many responses so fast. I really appreciate everyone's help!!!

Answer (score 1):

You game should probably start in its own thread and manage that itself (hard to say), but to get you going you could start your game in a new "external" thread, something like this in your actionPerformed:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Thread thread = new Thread("Game thread") {
        public void run() {
            startGame(); //or however you start your game
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
```

Comment: Unless this is an "frames-per-second" driven / continously animated application, I would say that starting a separate thread that *runs* the game seems like a bad idea. The actionPerfomed should just adjust the user interface, return, and wait for further user actions.

Comment: Well that is what I assumed as the game running is not returning, didn't sound very event driven to me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you want to extend [javax.swing.SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).

The non-ui start-up functionality would run in [doInBackground](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#doInBackground%28%29) and the [done](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#done%28%29) method would be called when it finishes to update the ui.

There's even an example in the javadoc Class Description to update a progressbar with the status of what's happening in start-up.